# Google Glass GDK Voice Input doesn't work anymore since update to XE22

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Since the last update of Google Glass I have a problem with voice commands. My app worked very well before the software update, but since it updated to XE22 the "ok glass" doesn't work anymore.

When I start the Glass and come to "ok Glass" screen, I can say "ok Glass" and the List of commads (Take a picture, Google, Make a call to, etc.) open. But then the voice input seems to freeze, when my applications are in this list too. The Glass doesn't react on "ok Glass" anymore. But this don't happen with all of my apps. Some of my apps are excepted, although I use the same way to define the keyword (e.g. like this: `<trigger keyword="Open my Application" />`).

The same problem occurs in the contextual menu. When I use only 3 contextual menu items, it works very well. But when I use more then 3 menu items the voice input freezes, too. Glass doesn't react on voice commands anymore and I need to restart Google Glass.

Before the update everything worked without any problems. I could start my apps in "ok Glass", as well as use contextual voice commands, which I have created exactly like here (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#using_unlisted_main_voice_commands).

Have anyone the same problem with the new software update, or does anyone know what to do? Did anything change in defining voice commands? I searched very long, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: No, I haven't had any issues yet with that.

Comment: Back in XE12, I ran into a home (ok glass) crashing issue with registering lots of voice triggers in my application. I'm not sure if that's what you're doing. My bug report to Google is here https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=448

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you use a built in voice command? (i.e. a `<trigger command=...` rather than `<trigger keyword=...` from the list https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command)

Comment: no it's not what i'm doing, but thanks! .. <trigger command:=""> is working very well, but opening the application is not my main problem. It works in most cases. There are only a few keywords that doesn't work. The main problem is the contextual voice menu. ok glass -> Open my app (works) -> ok glass -> menu opens (works). But then the glass doesn't react on my voice anymore. I have to restart it. The voice recognition seems to freeze in whole glass. The "ok glass" menu in my app is also gone. Touch gestures are working very well without any problems. It's just since XE22 update

Comment: Same problem I have now, XE22.